# So how i format this correctly

Tags: mysql, sql, json

I have the following table

| ID | Name | Currencies | Aliases |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | User | ["USD","EURO"] | {"User2":["3"]} |

I want to write SQL that returns the following result based on currencies and aliases to show people that have an alias of a user and users that have same currencies

| NAME | Currencies | Aliases |
| --- | --- | --- |
| User | 1 | NULL |
| User2 | NULL | 1 |

My initial SQL is the following

```
SELECT NAME 
FROM table 
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(Currencies,'"EURO"',"$") 
   OR JSON_CONTAINS(Aliases,'"3"',"$");
```

The problem with the code above that I can't differentiate if those users share the same aliases or the same currencies, it doesn't really need to be the same format of the table above anyway to diff is ok

btw i am using MySQL(10.5.10-MariaDB-1:10.5.10+maria~bionic)

samples:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table(
    ID INT,
    NAME VARCHAR(255),
    Currencies LONGTEXT,
    Aliases LONGTEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY(ID)
);
```

insert data:

```
REPLACE INTO table(ID, NAME, Currencies, Aliases) VALUES (:id, :name, :currencies, :aliases);
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: i am using MySQL (mariadb)

Comment: Thanks for providing sample data, but it's not clear how the input maps to the output.

Comment: Provide sample data as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts (current representation is not useful). Sample data must include all possible relation variations. Provide desired output for this data strictly, with explanations. Specify precise MySQL version.

Comment: i edited my post to specify the required samples

Answer (score 1):

If you want flags, just move the expressions to the `SELECT`:

```
SELECT NAME, JSON_CONTAINS(Currencies, '"EURO"', '$'),
       JSON_CONTAINS(Aliases, '"3"', '$') 
FROM table 
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(Currencies, '"EURO"', '$') OR
      JSON_CONTAINS(Aliases, '"3"', '$');
```